# Consecutive days of works

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools

I'm trying to make a scheduler with or-tool. I'm currently stuck with the following problem. I want the employees to work at least n consecutive days.

I tried this :

```
for n in all_nurses:
    for d in all_days:
        if sum([shifts[(n, d, 0)], shifts[(n, d, 1)], shifts[(n, (d), 2)]]) == 1: # if employee works this day, then he should works the 2 days after too
            model.Add(sum([shifts[(n, d+1, 0)], shifts[(n, (d+1), 1)], shifts[(n, (d+1), 2)]]) == 1)
            model.Add(sum([shifts[(n, d+2, 0)], shifts[(n, (d+2), 1)], shifts[(n, (d+2), 2)]]) == 1)
```

It works with 3 employees, but if I add more employees (10), the model doesn't find any solutions.

Would you have an idea ?

EDIT :
I tried to implement the example on https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/39f44709bba203f5ff3bc18fab8098739f189a6d/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py#L61
But I failed ..
Here is my attempt :

```
for n in all_nurses:
    works = [sum(shifts[n, d, s] for s in all_shifts) for d in all_days]
    print (works)
    for length in range(3, 4):
        for start in range(len(works) - length - 1):
            model.AddBoolOr(negated_bounded_span(works, start, length))
    for start in range(len(works) - 5 - 1):
        model.AddBoolOr([works[i].Not() for i in range(start, start + hard_max + 1)])
```

I get the error :

```
AttributeError: '_SumArray' object has no attribute 'Not'
```

I'm forced to make the sum of the shifts of the day, since I need consecutive days of work, but not in a specific shift.

Also, if someone has a good explanation on how works the method here : https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/39f44709bba203f5ff3bc18fab8098739f189a6d/examples/python
Because I really don't get it how AddBoolOr insure that we have a sequence of true consecutive booleans

EDIT 2 :

I succeeded to implement the solution on the github.
But, I still have a problem.
I created a mirror of my days/shifts like this :

```
shifts = {}
mirrors = {}
for n in all_nurses:
    for d in all_days:
        mirrors[(n,d)] = model.NewBoolVar('mirror_n%id%i' % (n, d))
        for s in all_shifts:
            shifts[(n, d, s)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_n%id%is%i' % (n, d,
                                                                      s))    


#Creation du mirroir
for n in all_nurses:
    for d in all_days:
        model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for s in all_shifts) == mirrors[(n,d)])
```

Such that for nurse 1 : 0010 0100 0010 1000 0000 0000 0000
Mirror would be : 1 1 1 1 0 0 0

Then I applied the method to have consecutive days of works on my mirror since he is linked to my principal table.

```
for n in all_nurses:
    works = [mirrors[n,d] for d in range(num_days)]
    for length in range(1, 3):
        for start in range(len(works) - length - 1):
            model.AddBoolOr(negated_bounded_span(works, start, length))
    for start in range(len(works) - 5 - 1):
        model.AddBoolOr([works[i].Not() for i in range(start, start + 5 + 1)])
```

Now, I would expect the result to not have any period of work not comprised between 3 and 5.
But still, when I print the solution, for one nurse, I got the following result :

```
0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000
```

And for the mirror it is :

```
1111100010
```

This should not be possible, since a period of work is comprised between 3 and 5.

Would you have an idea ?
Thanks!

Comment: Your further edit would be better asked as a new question. You can link to this one for background.

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented as a soft version in shift_scheduling_sat.py

See: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/39f44709bba203f5ff3bc18fab8098739f189a6d/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py#L61

in

```
    # Forbid sequences that are too short.
    for length in range(1, hard_min):
        for start in range(len(works) - length - 1):
            model.AddBoolOr(negated_bounded_span(works, start, length))
```

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but it is not really adapted to my problem,  look at the edited question :)

Comment: You should not use sum. You need an array of boolvars, not a array of sums.

Comment: Yes, I finally got it ... I resolved my problem with an other arrays of "worked day" who is a mirror of "shifts", but without the notion of shift, just if the person worked or not this day.

So it worked with the example you posted, but still, I implemented it, it works now, but I can't understand the logic behin. Why it insures that you'll have a sequence of true bools ? Do you have any doc on it ? Thanks!

Comment: logic says a implies b is not(a) or b. Thus if you have the start of a sequence of length2, then it is followed by another worked day. This translate into (worked[0] = 0 and worked[1] = 1 and worked[2] = 1) implies worked[3] = 1. This is then (worked[0] = 1 or worked[1] = 0 or worked[2] = 0 or worked[3] = 1). Same thing for a sequence of length 1 implies the following true.

Comment: But here : https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/sat/cp_model/CpModelBuilder/
It's stated that AddBoolOr will be ok if just one litteral is True.
So a sequence like [0,1,0,1,0] would be considered as a satisfied constraint, since we have some true litterals. And if we negate them it would be [1,0,1,0,1], so still ok..
I don't really get how it can insure that it will be continued.

Comment: Because you add all these constraints for all length < 3 and all starts. The only way all of them will be true if is the min sequence is >= 3.

Comment: I edited my question with a new problem on the same thing ...
Thanks for the explanation btw, I really appreciate!